# Ansible, передать results.stdout_lines в файл

Tags: ansible, scripts

День добрый. Есть скрипт (1.sh), который собирает информацию об ПК (проц, оперативка и т.д.).Через ansible копирую и запускаю скрипт на удаленной машине. Далее результат записываю на ansiblemaster в файл /tmp/whatever.out. Строка в whatever.out перезаписывается, а надо чтоб добавлялась от каждого ПК новая. Подскажи пожалуйста как это сделать.

```
- name: inventory
  hosts: pc
  become: yes

  vars:
    source_file: /root/scripts/1.sh
    destin_folder: /tmp

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to hosts
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_folder }} mode=0555

  - shell: |
      sh /tmp/1.sh
    register: results

  - name: Remove file hosts
    file: "path=/tmp/1.sh state=absent"

  - debug:
      var: results.stdout_lines

  - local_action:
      module: copy
      content: "{{ results.stdout_lines }}"
      dest: /tmp/whatever.out
```

Comment: Может `lineinfile`?

Comment: @don Rumata, спасибо, получилось. Но есть одна странность, если файл существует то добавляется как положено (две записи, т.к. два ПК опрашиваю), если файла нет то он создается и добавляется только одна запись (должно быть две) `- local_action: module: lineinfile dest: "/tmp/whatever.out" line: "{{ results.stdout_lines }}" create: yes`

Comment: Как проверочный костыль - сначала создай файл через `file: state=touch`